# Pretty print output with Python

Tags: python, output

I have a set of information, stored in a python dictionary, representing a dataset.

I have a structure like the following:

```
{
   "name": "Dataset name"
   "authors": ["Foo Bar", "Mickey Mouse"]
   "keywords" : ["Lorem", "ipsum", "door", "sit"]
   "description": "Sed pretium suscipit elit, ac euismod turpis aliquet vel. Curabitur placerat pharetra ipsum eu posuere. Nullam ut rutrum est, ut aliquam risus. Praesent efficitur lectus ac rhoncus hendrerit. Nulla facilisis metus sed purus faucibus mattis."
   "files": [ list of files ]
}
```

I am looking for a good package to display this information on the console in a pretty and easy-to-read way.

I was looking for a result like this:

```
#############################################################################
#                                 NAME                                      #
#############################################################################
# Authors:                                                                  #
#          - Mr. Foo Bar                                                    #
#          - Mickey Mouse                                                   #
#############################################################################
# Keywords:                                                                 #
#          - lorem                                                          #
#          - ipsum                                                          #
#          - dolor                                                          #
#############################################################################
# Description:                                                              #
#                                                                           #
# Sed pretium suscipit elit, ac euismod turpis aliquet vel. Curabitur plcea # 
# pharetra ipsum eu posuere. Nullam ut rutrum est, ut aliquam rises.        #
# Praesent efficitur lectus ac rhoncus hendrerit. Nula facilisis metus sed  # 
# purus faucibus mattis.                                                    #
#############################################################################

File                Description
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
main.py             Main file etc etc
test/test.h         test file dolor foo bar foo
```

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have the data already in a Python dict or in a text file? Because you mention *dictionary*.

Comment: sorry due to an error a part of message was missing. I have updated now.

Answer (score 0):

The best one is pprint, which is pretty print.

`import pprint`

`pprint.pprint(your_dict)`

Comment: sorry due to an error a part of message was missing. I have updated now.

Comment: I see what you want now. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any way to do that.

Comment: thank you anyway! I am starting to think that to achieve a layout similar to this, the only way is to write manually a custom implementation